# MIP's multiply x*y and divide by z

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on a online tutorial and I'm stumped on a excercise :

Write a program that determines the value of the following expression:

(x*y)/z

What I am stuck on is that after multiplying the number which is bigger than 32-bits I get the significant order bit in HI and the rest in LO. I used mfhi and mflo to store the values into 2 registers. But how do divide the product of x*y when after mfhi and mflo? The numbers are bigger than 32 bits is why I used ori and sll to get the correct number in.

```
ori $t1, 0x186A
sll $t1, $t1, 8

ori $t2, 0x1388
sll $t2, $t2, 4

ori $t3, 0x61A8
sll $t3, $t3, 4

multu $t1, $t2
mfhi $t4
mflo $t5
```

Thanks

Link to Tutorial Excercise #4: http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-14/ass14programs.html

Comment: Did you use the hint? Actually that hint doesn't work in general but you're probably supposed to use it here.

Comment: I'm quite not sure I get what they are saying or Im just fixated on something else. I understand that my products is bigger than 32 bits. The high order bits are in HI and low on LO. Now I want to divide that product by z, but Im confused as I got two numbers to deal with both HI and LO. Am I wrong to say if there is a way to combine HI and LO and then divide?

Comment: It's a silly exercise. You are expected to calculate `(x/z)*y` instead, realizing that `x mod z = 0`. But if you realized that you wouldn't stop there, and just calculate the whole thing at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for that...Busting my head over that lol. Thanks for all help and replies.

Comment: If you did need to do extended-precision division in MIPS, I'm not sure if there's any hardware 64b / 32b => 32b divsion (like x86 has).  gmplib doesn't have any div functions in the MIPS directory: https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/mips32.  So I guess it just uses the C fallback https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/generic/divrem_1.c to build an extended-precision division out of ordinary C `long / long` quotient and remainder.  (compiling to MIPS `divu`)